# How to build ICMP packets using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, network-programming, icmp

I need to switch the transformation of a file (FTP client) to my code in order to transfer the wanted file using the payload of one of the following protocols: 
ICMP - use ICMP packets to send the file OR using DNS packet to send the file. 
in each of the above methods we need to build packets from the specified protocol and sending them in a way that in each packet we can add a little bit of information to the file in a hidden way (this is in the foreign computer) while my computer awaits for these packets and then gathers them in to one file.

This is a part of an assignment and would like for some help how to start, 
was recommended using scapy in python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could find either [dpkt](http://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful. Once installed, you can explore them interactively. Try something like:

```
%% python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dpkt
>>> help(dpkt.icmp.ICMP)
```

Or try something like the [ICMP example from Scapy](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html?highlight=icmp):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP

p=sr1(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/ICMP())
if p:
    p.show()
```

You'll find DNS to be similar, but have different limitations on the payload they will support. In either case, you will have to do some payload manipulation to send parts of the file.